# Trouble with "do while"

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

this program expects a capital letter from user input. The input is saved in char variable c, after that converted to ascii, and then checked, if it really is a capital letter. When not, program should ask again. Problem ist, that command System.out.println("Write capital letter: ") is executed multiple times and it looks like that:

Write capital letter: 
Write capital letter: 
Write capital letter: 
Write capital letter: 
Write capital letter:

I want to have only one "Write capital letter: " on screen after every wrong input, and it needs to eb done with ascii table.

Thanks in advance.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int ascii;
char c;

do { 
  System.out.println("Write capital letter: ");
  c = (char) System.in.read();                                              
  ascii = (int) c;                                                         
} while (ascii < 65 || ascii > 90 );
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? What values do `c` and `ascii` have when the `while` statement happens?

Comment: Indeed, add something like `System.out.println( ascii )` after `ascii = (int) c;` and take a look at what value(s) you're getting.  Then look up what characters have those codes.

Comment: What causes the prompt to be shown multiple times is that when you read that one byte (the character) it leaves to `System.in` any other things on that line you inputted, including the line break.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Write capital letter: ");
do { 
  c = (char) System.in.read();                                              
  // ascii = (int) c;  // not needed if you are using the isUppercase() method          
  if(! Character.isUppercase(c)){
   System.out.println("Write capital letter: ");
  }                                            
} while (! Character.isUppercase(c) );
```

As long as the condition is true, whatever is defined in the `do` block is executed. So, move the statements you want to execute only once out of the `do` block.

Comment: You don't need the whole `ascii` variable then.

Comment: The OP wants a prompt multiple times: “I want to have only one "Write capital letter: " on screen after every wrong input, and it needs to eb done with ascii table.”  The question is about why it's appearing more often than OP expects it.

Comment: I tried it, but i still get multiple "Write capital letter:" after every wrong input.

Comment: @user2993023 Try using a `java.util.Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `System.in.read()` when you have a `BufferedReader` variable set?

This will solve your issue. I am using your `BufferedReader in` variable.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Write capital letter: ");
    int b = 0
    while ((b = in.read()) != -1){ 
        char c = (char) c;
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) break;
    }

    //Carry on...
}
```